# Custom setting and accessing it through JavaScript in Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to change minor visual things based on given Odoo instance role (production, testing, etc.). I don't need to do it through the website - a hard coded variable is what I'm thinking.
I currently have a module that contains JavaScript which handles it, but I don't know how to 1) set the `role` variable and 2) how to then access it in JavaScript on Odoo website.

What's the best way to do it?

I was thinking about adding a custom setting field in `openerp-wsgi.py`, like `conf['role'] = 'production'`, but I don't know if that's possible.

Thanks!